# pusher beam is not integrating in ios

Tags: ios, swift, pusher, swift5, pusherswift

i am integrating pusher beam with ios app. i am getting error while setting beamCleint user id. i am getting error "Optional(PushNotifications.TokenProviderError.error("[PushNotifications] - Changing the `userId` is not allowed."))" any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance
here is my code

````
let tokenProvider = BeamsTokenProvider(authURL: "............") { () -> AuthData in
            let sessionToken = "\(defaults.string(forKey: kUserToken ) ?? "")"
            let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(sessionToken)"]
            let queryParams: [String: String] = [:]
            return AuthData(headers: headers, queryParams: queryParams)
        }

        self.beamsClient.setUserId("\(userId)", tokenProvider: tokenProvider, completion: { error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error.debugDescription)
                return
            }

            print("Successfully authenticated with Pusher Beams")
        }) ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Have you previously set a userId on this device? You may need to ensure you have cleared the device state using the `clearAllState` method. See https://pusher.com/docs/beams/reference/ios#-clearallstate